# So I just got a voicemail from a random person, where it says 3 random numbers (for example 354) and then "goodbye"

Tags: random, bot

So basically, i was just playing games as always, and I get a voicemail. It reads-"396 (random numbers just incase the numbers are sensitive information), goodbye" It sounds automated but i'm not sure, should I be concerned and do something or just ignore it? FYI, somebody kept trying to break into my account before this and this happened when i enabled 2 step verification without a call. If somebody can please explain how to defend myself in this situation please do so. Thank you!

Comment: are there 7 or 10 "random" numbers? are the first 3 an area code? Sound like a generic message got cut off at the beginning, and all that got recorded was the callback number.

Comment: yes, to be exact it says- 2....7....9....goodbye.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a cut message.

Your voicemail picked the phone: "Kevin Phelan is not able to talk with you, you may leave a voicemail if you wish..."

At the same time, the calling bot started telling its offer "Hello dear customer, we will sell you the most delicious pickles you have tasted, please call us back at the 123456"(The voicemail intro ends and starts recording) "279. Goodbye"

Of course, we have no idea if they wanted to sell you food, furniture, encourage you to vote, or if it was a call providing a 2FA code.

The fact that there is a goodbye hints that there was some more text at the beginning, that would probably identify what their numbers were for.

Note that *even if it was* for 2FA, there's no harm by not having picked it. On your next legit login you would get called again, you don't need a 2FA code provided in a missed phone call.